# I am trying to calculate `10 * (50 / 100)` and I got back `0` but when I did `10 * 50 / 100` I got back `5`!

Tags: ruby, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby Refuses to Divide Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448036/ruby-refuses-to-divide-correctly)

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and when I try to calculate `10 * (50 / 100)` I got back `0` but when I make `10 * 50 / 100` I got back `5`.

For technical reasons, I can not use the latter since my code is like the following:

```
perc = 50 /100

# Some code that uses the 'perc' variable
... = method_name(perc)

return 10 * perc
```

What should I make to solve the problem and have `5` (*not* `5.0` or something else; that is, so that the returns is an `Integer`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

50 / 100 is 0 because you are using integer division. The result is truncated to an integer.

Performing the multiplication first works because then the division gives a whole number.

You could perform the calculation using floats instead of integers: 50.0 / 100.0 == 0.5, then round the result to an integer at the end of the calculation.

```
proportion = 50.0 / 100.0
result = (10 * proportion).round
return result
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/8TUWZ)

Comment: @Mark Byers - I know, but how can I solve the problem since, for technical reasons, it must return 5?

Comment: `50.0/100` will be shorter :D

Answer (score 2):

50/100 will return 0 in integer division, if you try 50.0/100.0, you will get .5.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Ruby, but I assume the answer is in the order of operations.

In case of `10 * (50 / 100)`, the program first calculates `(50 / 100)`, which results in `0.5`. Since you are working with integers, this is rounded to `0`, thus explaining why `10 * (50 / 100) = 0`.

In case of `10 * 50 / 100`, the program first calculates `10 * 50`, which is `500`. Next it divides this result by `100`, and you get `10 * 50 / 100 = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your question is about [typecasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) .

If you want to get 5 as a result of `return 10 * perc` but not 5.0, then you should cast it to integer, like `return (Integer) 10 * perc` or `return (10 * perc).to_i`